# Group by multiple formatted and casted columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, group-by, multiple-columns, ordinals

I've a trouble grouping my multiple column in SQL server. I'm aware that Group by ordinals does not work and also, I cannot use the alias name in Group by. 
It's painful to list the columns especially if I've formatted and casted the columns in SELECT statements.

e.g.

```
SELECT 
CONCAT('ABC',column1) AS col1,
cast('XYZ AS VARCHAR) AS col2, 
column3 AS col3, 
cast(ISNULL(column4,0) AS MONEY) / 100 AS col4, 
....
....
count(DISTINCT table2.ID) AS col15
GROUP BY <>
```

Above is a sample query which I use and it's complex when I select different columns from different table JOINing them. What's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to achieve this outcome, the only mechanisms are to use either a Sub-Query or CTE:

**Sub-Query:**

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
        SELECT
            CONCAT('ABC',column1) AS col1,
            cast('XYZ AS VARCHAR) AS col2, 
            column3 AS col3, 
            cast(ISNULL(column4,0) AS MONEY) / 100 AS col4, 
            ....
            ....
            count(DISTINCT table2.ID) AS col15
        )
GROUP BY <>
```

**Common Table Expression (CTE):**

```
;WITH data AS (
    SELECT
            CONCAT('ABC',column1) AS col1,
            cast('XYZ AS VARCHAR) AS col2, 
            column3 AS col3, 
            cast(ISNULL(column4,0) AS MONEY) / 100 AS col4, 
            ....
            ....
            count(DISTINCT table2.ID) AS col15
    )
SELECT *
FROM Data
GROUP BY <>
```